# How can two doubles be conflicting types?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


int main(void){
  double a=0,r=0,n=0;
  printf("Enter Constant a:");
  scanf("%lf",&a);
  printf("Enter Constant r:");
  scanf("%lf",&r);
  printf("Enter Variable n:");
  scanf("%lf",&n);

  double an;
  an = geom_rec(a,r,n);    // Line 15

  return 0;
}

double geom_rec(double a,double r,double n){    // Line 20
  double ans=a;
  return a;
}
```

Errors:

```
Line 20: error: conflicting types for 'geom_rec'
Line 15: error: previous implicit declaration of 'geom_rec' was here
```

Answer (score 12):

You forgot to create a prototype for the function.

Put the following before your `main` function (you could also move the whole function above `main`):

```
double geom_rec(double a,double r,double n);
```

If you call a function that wasn't defined or prototyped before, the compiler assumes it to return `int` - which is conflicting with your actual return type.

Comment: :P thx, im just learning in my class and i forget these things sometimes. THX SO MUCH!

Comment: Ouch, that answer's score hurts realizing that it actually got me zero rep increase :p

Answer (score 4):

You can either put a prototype for the function before `main()`, or place the function itself before `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler reached line 15 it hadn't seen a function `geom_rec` before, so it assumed the function returns `int`.

Later, on line 20, you define the function as returning a `double` and accepting 3 `double` arguments, which is different than what the compiler "knew" about the function. So it complained, giving you a chance to define a proper prototype for the function **before** using it.